# Is a comma needed in this sentence?

Tags: sentence-structure, comma

I have a question regarding if I should or should not add a comma in this sentence, just before "zu lernen". 
Is it necessary? Is it a must to separate the sentence in two? Would it be incorrect if I leave it like this?

> Das wirklich Schwierige in Deutsch ist die Artikel zu lernen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You would place the comma before "die Artikel zu lernen", if at all. This comma is facultative.

> Das wirklich Schwierige ist(,) die Artikel zu lernen.

It's not easy to know when a comma is necessary, when optional and when plainly wrong. The rule that applies here is [§75 E2](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Amtlich/Interpunktion/pgf71-79.html#pgf75-E2). There's also [a good summary](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/PartAdjInf.html?lang=de) that is very helpful.

Comment: Could you elaborate why do you think that §75(3) does not apply here, which would make the comma necessary? I'd say "Das" qualifies as reference word as it is required by this rule.